# Relating Unique ID

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, relational-database

Just a really quick question that I can't seem to find an answer for. I'm making these tables, and I have been told that every table needs to have some form of random unique ID, that is separate to the PK. My question is if I can relate two tables with UID/FK in the same way you would PK/FK.

Is this bad practice? What are the advantages/disadvantages?

Comment: Who told you that, and in what context? It's true that it is frequently recommended to use a random, non-sequential ID when passing info through a URL, for example, but is not generally necessary if the unique value isn't exposed to the world or end user. In other words, not every table needs it.

Comment: I'm doing it as part of a migration project in an internship. My mentor if you will on the team said every table should have an ID column, and the PK should be kept seperate from that ID.

Comment: If the PK values are not exposed externally, I don't see much value in it. For the same reason only the _exterior_ doors on my house have heavy deadbolt locks. The purpose of an incrementing PK column is to enforce uniqueness and you don't really need _double_ uniqueness.

Comment: So, the advice is to have in all tables both a Primary Key (sequentially generated or a natural key?) and a (randomly generated) Unique Key?

Comment: It would be like having an employee table. The SSN is the primary key, and then there would be another random unique ID

Answer (score 0):

Your "mentor" is right in a sense.  In migrations and in BI star schema DWH's, it's best to come up with a new UID.

The reason for this: when joining like tables together, it's possible to have primary keys that are matches, or different formats.

Though, as others have said, it isn't necessary.  Just best practice when joining data in a BI environment.

Hope that helps.

Comment: OK i think I understand that. But if you are going to be using the UID to relate tables with one another. What's to stop there being the same issues with matching or formats(unless you conciously decide to keep them all as a number lets say). Also, whats the point in even having the PK, if you can use the UID to relate and identify records in the table?

Comment: The UID is only necessary when joining two tables with their own PK's.  Like if you're joining example tables table_customer_data and table_order_status. Table_customer_data might have Cust_Num as a PK and table_order_status might have Order_Num.  These could be unique identifiers in their own perspective tables, but might overlap in the table of combined data.  Thus, the need to create a new PK for each record in the table.

Comment: Sorry you have lost me there again. Cust_Num and Order_Num are PKs in their own tables. But because they overlap in the table of combined data, you'll need a new PK for each record in the new table?

Why are you combining the two tables, or are you talking about a resolving table like Customer_Order?

Comment: Yes, a resolving table.  Otherwise, not necessary, as I mentioned.